# Does 'git log' use Depth First Search traversal to display the commits?

Tags: git, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to understand the order in which 'git log' displays the commits. My belief is that 'git log' performs a DFS (Depth-First Search).
I know that commits in git follow a DAG structure.
Thanks,
Anda

Comment: I’m not sure, but git uses directed asymmetric graph. I’m pretty sure it only shows the current node (head) and all its parents. Does this information help? (I just saw you’ve already mentioned that)

Comment: i think you meant acyclic instead of asymmetric. Indeed, it shows the current node, then its parent(s), then its grandparents and so on. Sounds like DFS to me, but not clear how it works for the merge commits.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I know merge commits have multiple parents. I’m assuming it follows all parents up the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log` *does not* do a depth-first search.  However, what it does can't quite be described as breadth-first either.

The actual algorithm is to use a priority queue.  Each commit to be visited initially, based on command-line arguments, is inserted into the priority queue.  Then, upon visiting a commit, its parents are inserted after making any modifications due to history simplification (or are omitted due to being already visited / in-the-queue).  When the current visit is done, the next commit comes off the priority queue to be visited.

The priority of each commit, as it gets inserted into the queue, is based on command-line sort options:

- default: priority = committer date, higher date = higher priority (more to front of queue)
- `--date-order`: priority = children > parents; but if a pair of commits is unrelated, committer date as usual
- `--author-date-order`: priority = children > parents, but if a pair of commits is unrelated, use author date instead of committer date
- `--topo-order` (turned on automatically by `--graph`): children > parents; when splitting a merge commit, group all children in each "leg" together.

Note that there's no "priority = author date" that *doesn't* also require children-before-parents, even though the *default* order allows children-before-parents.

(Internally, the code is messier than this description, due to `--boundary` handling, `--reverse`, `--skip`, and `--max-count`, but the above is sort of the *goal* anyway.)

---

Note that `git log -g` (which walks the reflogs) is quite different: it always runs in reflog order, and will visit commits multiple times if appropriate.